# Laravel Queue running big jobs

Tags: laravel, queue, terraform, devops, jobs

I have an API running on Laravel. One of the routes, is to send a file.

I have a script, written in python, which optimizes the file. This script uses a lot of RAM, which is why I would like to run it on a different server than the main API server.

The simplest solution is therefore to have a second powerful server running my "optimize_file" Laravel Queue.

This creates several problems:

- the powerful server is very expensive, and runs constantly
- if there is an influx of files to optimize, this single server is not enough ...

Ideally, I would like to create a server for each file to be optimized. A file is sent -> Server creation -> File optimization -> Server deletion. (I don't know if this is a good practice)

Have you ever encountered this kind of situation? How did you do ?

Comment: Look into serverless functions: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/ or https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/

Comment: @HelderSepulveda thank you for your answer :) the problem is that these solutions are limited in terms of RAM (for AWS, 10GB, for Google Cloud Functions 8GB ...), the script which optimizes the files needs 32GB to 128GB of RAM depending on the size of the file to be optimized

Comment: This is quite offtopic for StackOverflow ... for such a huge ram requirements you probably need to created your own "job orchestrator" to start/stop servers on demand ... also look at that script see if you can refactor it to use a distributed MapReduce technique to achieve the same optimization